# Unity: Nav Mesh Agent doesn't remain inside character

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, navmesh

I'm seeing that the Nav Mesh Agent of my character doesn't stay "inside" the character.
I noticed that in the Scene inspector and saw the outline of the Nav Mesh Agent moving from my character as if they're colliding with each other.
I've found no solutions for this issue so far.
Any ideas what may cause this to happen?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbled upon this issue, the reason the NavMeshAgent didn't stay inside my character was because I handled the character's movement incorrectly.
I used `CharacterController.Move()` when I should've used `NavMeshAgent.Move()`.
That solved my problem.